# What to use in Azure for Scheduling and calling custom function (worker)

Tags: c#, azure, scheduler, worker

I would like to have a Worker Process to run independently from Websites in Azure. I will use this worker to create Websites and databases dynamically so I don't want WebJobs.

To create theses websites I would like to be able to call the Worker from a WebService in c#.

Also, I want to schedule task to clean databases each day.  I read at some places that I need Azure Scheduler or Worker Role with Quartz.net.

I would like to know what is the best solution in Azure for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I understood it seems like you want to build an automation process and be able to manage it.

I think Azure Automation could possibly be one option for you.

Azure Automation is an Azure service for simplifying cloud management through process automation. Using Azure Automation, manual, frequently-repeated, long-running, and error-prone tasks can be automated to increase reliability, efficiency, and time to value for your organization.

Azure Automation provides a highly-reliable, highly-available workflow execution engine that scales to meet your needs. In Azure Automation, processes can be kicked off manually, by 3rd-party systems, or at scheduled intervals so that tasks happen exactly when needed.

For more details you can take a look at the Azure Automation here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/automation/

Answer (score 2):

Another vote for Azure Automation. You should be able to easily call it from your web service by using the Automation's own API.

If your databases are Azure SQL Databases (the managed Azure service) then you could use [Azure Elastic database jobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-jobs-overview/) to perform the daily cleanup.
If not, then Azure Scheduler would be my choice as well.